# How can I get columns in a table in iTextSharp to automatically calculate their width?

Tags: .net, pdf, itext, pdf-generation

I have a table that I'm creating in iTextSharp and populating with data at runtime. The number of columns are variable and the text in them could be any size.

When I create the table at the moment, the columns are the same size. However, some columns have wasted space and others have cramped content. I want the columns to automatically resize themselves to best contain their content.

```
var table = new PdfPTable(columnCount) { WidthPercentage = 100};
```

How can I get my desired behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you can't autosize the columns. You can however, give columns relative widths or weights.